# Creating variations of prompts for ChatGPT

Tags: nlp, text, spacy, chatbot

I am developing a fine tune model to emulate a tech support chatbot based on my given information. I am struggling to create a large dataset (aiming for 1000 prompt/completion pairs), does anyone have good recommendations for nlp text augmentation tools to use?

I have tried nlpaug which does synonym replacement, but I am looking for something more nuanced - that will provide intelligent variations of a given prompt.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You can also ask itself ChatGPT to paraphrase the prompts you are preparing.

Comment: yes I have done that but I am looking for more options to get a large dataset